# Inconsistent behavior using cache through a library

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a web app that pulls data from several large spreadsheets, and we wanted to setup a cache to speed up the app, while allowing the sheets to update the cache as necessary.

Essentially we have a cache script containing functions for getting the cache, setting a new cache entry, and some test functions for clearing/updating. The web app is able to pull the cache without a problem, but when the sheets try to replace a cached entry (by using the put(key,value,time) function), the updated info doesn't appear when getting the cache in the web app.

To simplify things, I created four barebones test scripts:

1. Cache script

   ```
   function getCache() {
     var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
     var cached = cache.get("test");

     if (cached != null) {
       return cached;
     }

     cache.put("test", "a new cache", 1500);
     cached = cache.get("test");
     return cached;
   }

   function clearCache() {
     var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
     cache.remove("test");
   }

   function updateCache(contents) { 
     var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
     cache.put('test', contents);
   }
   ```
2. Output script (index.html has a clearcache button that calls the clearCache() function below)

   ```
   function doGet() {
     var cache = cacher.getCache();
     var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
     return html.append(JSON.stringify(cache, null, 2));
   }

   function clearCache() {
     cacher.clearCache()
   }
   ```
3. Update Cache script

   ```
   function updateCache() {
     var contents = "Here is new data";
     cacher.updateCache(contents);
   }
   ```
4. Second Update Cache script

   ```
   function updateCache() {
     var contents = "Here is new data 2";
     cacher.updateCache(contents);
   }
   ```

Scripts #2,3, and 4 all use #1 as a library, kept on development mode to use the latest version. I've done this test twice, creating the scripts from scratch. 
The first instance of this test, the second update script, #4, won't update the cache. Running it's updateCache() function, then reloading the web app part of #2, it should say "Here is new data 2", but only shows "a new cache."

In the second instance of the test, both #3 and #4 updated the cache successfully. I cannot for the life of me find out why it fails in one case but not in the other. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It seems like based on the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) that a cache is a non-shared resource, so the only cache that should exist is through the library, but in the failing case, it seems like it's "put"ing to a separate cache?

Comment: After a week of issues related to this, it suddenly began working today without any changes. That's pretty annoying, and makes me wonder if something was going on with maintenance on Google's side?